# Re-number chapter NUMBERS with P?, S? for problem solution book template with parts

Tags: book-design, parts

How to go about renumbering the chapter numbers to reflect P1 for problem 1, S1 for solution 1 etc. in a book template with parts.

Instead of having to manually `\renewcommand` each time, is it possible to have it done automatically?

Here is the code that I currently have:

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt,letterpaper,draft]{book}
\begin{document}
  \part{Text Part 1}
  Text to be included as a paragraph below custom part. The text should be on the same page just under the heading.
  \chapter{Problem 1}
  Here is my text for Problem 1.
  \chapter{Solution 1}
  Here is my text for Solution 1.
  \chapter{Conclusion 1}
  Here is my text for Conclusion 1.
  \part{Text Part 2}
  Text to be included as a paragraph below custom part. The text should be on the same page just under the heading.
  \chapter{Problem 2}
  Here is my text for Problem 2.
  \chapter{Solution 2}
  Here is my text for Solution 1.
  \chapter{Conclusion 2}
  Here is my text for Conclusion 2.
  \part{Appendix}
  Text to be included as a paragraph below custom part. The text should be on the same page just under the heading.
  \chapter{Appendix 1}
  Here is my text for Appendix 1.
  \chapter{Appendix 2}
  Here is my text for Appendix 2.
  
\end{document}
```

Here is an example of what I want to accomplish:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: As it stands I really don't understand what you want to do. It looks like you want different sorts of chapters depending on their content. If that's the case, then make new `\chapter` commands to do that, each with their own counter. The `titlesec` package can help with that.

Comment: Will you always have a `\part` that has a Problem, then a Solution, followed by a Conclusion, and only one of these sets per `\part`? If so, your chapters could be numbered according to `\part`.

Comment: @Werner, yes, each `\part` will have just those 3 chapters....except for the Appendix